# Expander Handler Issue? System.Exception: 'Handler not found for view Xamarin.CommunityToolkit.UI.Views.Expander.'

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, maui, xamarin-community-toolkit, maui-community-toolkit

I'm using Visual Studio 2022 preview 2.0 MAUI. I want to used a expander in MAUI, I have used Xamarin.CommunityToolkit.MauiCompat  nuget. But I am seeing the exception `System.Exception: 'Handler not found for view Xamarin.CommunityToolkit.UI.Views.Expander.` How can I resolve this issue in MAUI.

My UI is:

```
<behaviors:Expander>
    <behaviors:Expander.Header>
        <HorizontalStackLayout Margin="33,-10,22,10">
            <Label FontAttributes="Bold" WidthRequest="230" VerticalOptions="Center" Text="Monday" TextColor="{DynamicResource Black}" FontSize="{DynamicResource AppFontSize_Default}"></Label>
            <Image Margin="0,0,30,0" Source="plus.png"  HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" WidthRequest="15" HeightRequest="20">
                <Image.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger TargetType="Image" Binding="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type behaviors:Expander}}, Path=IsExpanded}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Source" Value="plus.png" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Image.Triggers>
            </Image>
            <RadioButton  BackgroundColor="Transparent" BorderColor="{DynamicResource DefaultColor}"></RadioButton>
        </HorizontalStackLayout>
    </behaviors:Expander.Header>
    <behaviors:Expander.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Label Text="{Binding CustomerNotes}" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" TextColor="Black" FontSize="14" Padding="10,0,0,0"></Label>
        </DataTemplate>
    </behaviors:Expander.ContentTemplate>
</behaviors:Expander>
```

I have downloaded the nuget:

1. Xamarin.CommunityToolkit.MauiCompat
2. Xamarin.CommunityToolkit.Markup.MauiCompat

Also I have add handler on my `MauiProgram.cs` page

```
// Register ALL handlers in the Xamarin Community Toolkit assembly
handlers.AddCompatibilityRenderers(typeof(Xamarin.CommunityToolkit.UI.Views.MediaElementRenderer).Assembly);

// Register just one handler for the control you need
handlers.AddCompatibilityRenderer(typeof(Xamarin.CommunityToolkit.UI.Views.MediaElement), typeof(Xamarin.CommunityToolkit.UI.Views.MediaElementRenderer));
```

Comment: @Gerald Versluis  Do you have any idea ?? for How can i resolve this expander issue ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure how well the Xamarin Forms Community Toolkit works with MAUI. The [Maui Community Toolkit](https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/Maui) is still in pre-release, but they have plans to add the Expander Control.

You can track the [Expander proposal issue on Github](https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/Maui/issues/109).